# Removing a specific widget from table

Tags: java, widget, libgdx

I have 2 buttons created by only using

```
   table.addActor(new TextButton("Test Button_1", skin));
   table.addActor(new TextButton("Test Button_2", skin));
```

How do I remove Test Button_1 or would I have to clear the table in general?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a widget from a layout widget (lw) you get the index for that widget on your lw & :

`exampleTable.getChildren().removeIndex(index)`;